# How to trim string after two or three commas in a string

Tags: java, android, string, substring

I have a string like

```
"Domlur, Old Hal Airport Road, Bangalore, Karnataka"
```

In this string i wanted to store only "Domlur, Old Hal Airport Road" and trim rest of the string.

After few research in Google i thought i would get some help here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this pattern fixed?

Comment: Ya i would get string everytime in same manner.

Comment: Just split the string with comma and get what you want from the resulting array

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this..

```
String text = "Domlur, Old Hal Airport Road, Bangalore, Karnataka";
String[] text_array = text.split(",");
String result = text_array[0]+","+text_array[1];
Log.v("result",result);
```

Comment: I should concatenate text_array[0] and text_array[1] value to get one string again right.?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using regexp like this:

```
    String text = "Domlur, Old Hal Airport Road, Bangalore, Karnataka";
    Log.v(text.replaceAll("(.*),(.*),.*,.*", "$1,$2"));
```

Here we are matching each part of incoming string in our patter and picking only first two to achieve desired result.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please use the split() method of String class. you can split the string and store in an array then you can use it as you expected.

Comment: Ya i have split example but i am not sure how to split based on two commas.

Comment: Once you split the string, it will be stored as an array. from the array you can fetch the elements which you want. Please try the below after split the string.

String tmpStr = urArray[0]+urArray[1]; 
this will give you the result which you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Just use split(",") for String Class to get Array of "," Seperated values.

```
String data = "Domlur, Old Hal Airport Road, Bangalore, Karnataka" ;
String dataArray[] =  data.split(",");  
for(int i=0;i<dataArray.length;i++){
dataArray[i] = dataArray[i].trim(); // Here i am using trim() for removing space in left and right 
 }
```

Or you can do it Simpler

```
System.out.println(data.split(",")[0]+","+data.split(",")[1]);
```

Comment: Please add some Explanation for the code so that it helps the OP

Answer (score 0):

```
StringTokenizer strTok = new StringTokenizer("Domlur, Old Hal Airport Road, Bangalore, Karnataka","," );
StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();

strBuilder.append(strTok.nextElement()).append(",").append(strTok.nextElement());
String result = String.valueOf(strBuilder);
```